# array data not inserted in mysql database

Tags: jsp, servlets

i tried to upload a excel file as .csv extention and file uploaded successfully
and i got the excel sheet data in array
but i cant pass to the mysql database the connection establishes but data not passes.i have not getting any error during run time but even single data not pass 
please help me out!

```html
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %> 
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %> 
<%@ page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Date" %>
 <% 
String contentType = request.getContentType(); 
if ((contentType != null) && (contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0)) 
{ 
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream()); 
int formDataLength = request.getContentLength(); 
byte dataBytes[] = new byte[formDataLength]; 
int byteRead = 0; 
int totalBytesRead = 0; 

while (totalBytesRead < formDataLength) 
{ 
byteRead = in.read(dataBytes, totalBytesRead, formDataLength); 
totalBytesRead += byteRead; 
} 
String file = new String(dataBytes); 
String saveFile = file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10); 
System.out.println("saveFile=" + saveFile); 
saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\")+ 1,saveFile.indexOf("\"")); 
System.out.println("saveFile: " + saveFile); 

saveFile = file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10); 
saveFile = saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf("\n")); 
saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\")+ 1,saveFile.indexOf("\"")); 

int lastIndex = contentType.lastIndexOf("="); 
String boundary = contentType.substring(lastIndex + 1,contentType.length()); 

int pos; 
pos = file.indexOf("filename=\""); 
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1; 
/* pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1; 
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;  */

int boundaryLocation = file.indexOf(boundary, pos) - 4; 
int startPos = ((file.substring(0, pos)).getBytes()).length; 
int endPos = ((file.substring(0, boundaryLocation)).getBytes()).length; 
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(saveFile); 
fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, (endPos - startPos)); 
%> 
<b>File <% out.println(saveFile); %> has been uploaded and inserted into Database.</b> 
<%
Connection con=null; 
Statement pst=null; 
String line = null; 
String value=null; 
ResultSet rs=null;
try 
{ 
 
 StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder(); 
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(saveFile)); 
    String id="",name="",age="",address="",pincode="",status="";
   while (( line = input.readLine()) != null) 
 { 
 String arr[]=  line.split(",");
  for(int i=0 ;i<arr.length;i++)
  {
   if(i==0)
   {
    id=arr[i];
    name="";
    age="";
    address="";
    pincode="";
    status="";
   }
   if(i==1)
   {
    name=arr[i];
    age="";
    address="";
    pincode="";
    status="";
   }
   if(i==2)
   {
    age=arr[i];
    address="";
    pincode="";
    status="";
   }
   if(i==3)
   {
    address=arr[i];
    pincode="";
    status="";
   }
   if(i==4)
   {
    pincode=arr[i];
    status="";
   }
   if(i==5)
   {
    status=arr[i];
   }
   
   
  if(id!=""&&name!=""&&age!=""&&address!=""&&pincode!=""&&status!="")
  {
   System.out.println("ID: "+id+" Name:"+name+" Age:"+age+" Address:"+address+" pincode:"+pincode+" status:"+status);
    
  }
   
  /*  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
        Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/movie", "root", "mysql"); 


      int appid=Integer.parseInt(id);
      System.out.println("appid:"+appid);
      
      System.out.println("name:"+name);
      
      int cage=Integer.parseInt(age);
      System.out.println("age:"+age);
      
      System.out.println("address:"+address);
      
      int pin=Integer.parseInt(pincode);
      System.out.println("pin:"+pin);
      
      int stat=Integer.parseInt(status);
      System.out.println("status:"+stat);
      
      String progress="open";
      System.out.println("progress:"+progress);
      
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
       String CurruntDate = sdf.format(new Date());
       System.out.println("Currunt date:" +CurruntDate);
       
        HttpSession session1=request.getSession(false); 
        String userid=(String)session1.getAttribute("userid");
        System.out.println("session userid:"+userid);
        
        PreparedStatement ps1=(PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("insert into transaction values("+appid+",'"+name+"',"+cage+",'"+address+"',"+pin+","+stat+",'"+CurruntDate+"','"+progress+"','"+userid+"')"); 
           rs=(ResultSet) ps1.executeQuery();
           // pst=con.createStatement(); 
         // pst.executeUpdate("insert into transaction values("+appid+",'"+name+"',"+cage+",'"+address+"',"+pin+","+stat+",'"+CurruntDate+"','"+progress+"','"+userid+"')"); 
             */
  
  }
     contents.append(line); 
     
 } 

               
         int appid=Integer.parseInt(id);
         System.out.println("appid:"+appid);
         
         System.out.println("name:"+name);
         
         int cage=Integer.parseInt(age);
         System.out.println("age:"+age);
         
         System.out.println("address:"+address);
         
         int pin=Integer.parseInt(pincode);
         System.out.println("pin:"+pin);
         
         int stat=Integer.parseInt(status);
         System.out.println("status:"+stat);
         
         String progress="open";
         System.out.println("progress:"+progress);
         
         SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
         String CurruntDate = sdf.format(new Date());
      System.out.println("Currunt date:" +CurruntDate);
      
      HttpSession session1=request.getSession(false); 
      String userid=(String)session1.getAttribute("userid");
      System.out.println("session userid:"+userid);
  
      
      
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/movie";
      String username="root";
      String password="mysql";
      String query="insert into transaction(applicationid, customername, customerage, customeraddress, pincode, status, edate, progress, euserid) VALUES("+id+",'"+name+"',"+age+",'"+address+"',"+pincode+","+status+",'"+CurruntDate+"','"+progress+"','"+userid+"') ";
      Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
      System.out.println("connection established");
        //Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
     // stmt.executeQuery(query); 
  // System.out.println("ID: "+id+" Name:"+name+" Age:"+age+" Address:"+address+" pincode:"+pincode+" status:"+status);
            
      
    PreparedStatement ps1=(PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("insert into transaction(applicationid, customername, customerage, customeraddress, pincode, status, edate, progress, euserid) VALUES("+id+",'"+name+"',"+age+",'"+address+"',"+pincode+","+status+",'"+CurruntDate+"','"+progress+"','"+userid+"') "); 
       ps1.executeUpdate();
       //  pst=con.createStatement();
       // pst.executeUpdate("insert into userone values(111,'vikas','agartala')");
      //pst.executeQuery("insert into transaction(applicationid, customername, customerage, customeraddress, pincode, status, edate, progress, euserid) VALUES("+id+",'"+name+"',"+age+",'"+address+"',"+pincode+","+status+",'"+CurruntDate+"','"+progress+"','"+userid+"') ");

      pst.close();
} 

catch(Exception e) 
{} 

} 
%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write query in this fashion

```html
String query = "insert into transaction(applicationid, customername, customerage, customeraddress, pincode, status, edate, progress, euserid)
VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";  // The total ? is 9 as your total columns is 9

PreparedStatement ps1=(PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(query);
                ps1.setInterger(1,id);   // set your datatype whatever it is 
                ps1.setString(2,name);   // set your datatype whatever it is 
                ps1.setInteger(3,age);   // set your datatype whatever it is 
                ps1.setString(4,address);// set your datatype whatever it is 
                ps1.setInteger(5,pincode);// set your datatype whatever it is 
                ps1.setString(6,status); // set your datatype whatever it is 
                ps1.setString(7,CurrentDate);// set your datatype whatever it is 
                ps1.setString(8,progress);// set your datatype whatever it is 
                ps1.setInteger(9,userid);// set your datatype whatever it is 
                ps1.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: thanks for the help but when i set the datatypes to variables it gives error that gives me datatype mismatch error and whenever all datatypes  set as string then it gives me error like that   CurruntDate  can not be resolve to variable error what can i do?

Comment: Set the datatypes according to the datatypes you set in your database